About the Visibility Rules of Postgres MVCC
I'm trying to understand the MVCC behavior of Postgres.
By default, Postgres' MVCC distinguishes the version by giving the physical tuple a system column xmin, xmax.
We also understand that, depending on the isolation level, we obtain snapshot based on the visibility rule at the time the transaction starts or SQL Statement is executed.
It is understood that the xmin of snapshot is the minimum of 100 for the active transaction under the following circumstances, and xmax is 102 which is the xid of the next incremental transaction.
In this situation, the visibility rule is for xmin, xmax in the tuple
(xmin <= snapshot.xmin) and (xmin NOT IN xip)
AND
(snapshot.xmax < xmax OR xmax == null OR xmax IN xip)
I understand that it is.
Example image
However, this seems to cause a situation in which xid (101) needs to update a specific row and see the new version committed on snapshot, but not see it.
I am studying by referring to the documents below.
link1
link2

Did you check the official documentation?

I didn't read the entire official document in detail, but there was no explanation in the Concurrency Control section.
I would really appreciate it if you could let me know any official documents that can help me understand the Postgres MVCC mechanism

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transactions.html should tell you all there is to know about transactions and how PostgreSQL handles them.
